What is the domain of the function $\sqrt{\dfrac{x-a}{x+a}}$
The domain of the function $\displaystyle f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{x-a}{x+a}}$ is determined by two conditions:

The expression inside the square root must be non-negative:
$$
   \frac{x-a}{x+a} \geq 0
   $$

The denominator must not be zero:
$$
   x + a \neq 0 \quad \text{or} \quad x \neq -a
   $$


To solve
$$
   \frac{x-a}{x+a} \geq 0,
   $$
we analyze the sign of the expression.
excluding ( $x = -a$ ) to avoid division by zero.
So, the domain is:
$$
   (-\infty, -a) \cup [a, \infty)
   $$
Now suppose $a=-2$, then domain is $(-\infty, -(-2)) \cup [-2, \infty)$ = $\mathbb{R}$
But when $a = -2, x \ne 2$. Clearly domain is not $\mathbb{R}$.
Where is the error, and why?

The condition for denominator $\ne0$ is not $[x\ne a\lor x\ne -a]$. It's $[x\ne-a]$. I should impress upon you the fact that for $a\ne0$ the condition $[x\ne a\lor x\ne -a]$ is true for all $x$.

Are you sure $a\ge0$?

When you wrote that the domain is $(-\infty, -a) \cup [a, \infty)$, you implicitly assumed that $a > 0$.

@SassatelliGiulio Not true, try $a=2$ for example.

When $a\geq0$, we have $-a\leq a$, then your domain is$$(-\infty, -a) \cup [a, \infty).$$

But when $a<0$, we have $-a>a$, then your domain is$$(-\infty, a] \cup (-a, \infty).$$
This is why you take $a=-2$ but found a contradiction.

So to sum up, the domain is$$(-\infty, -|a|~]~ \cup ~[~|a|, \infty)~\backslash~\{-a\} .$$

Not an answer, just an addendum.
Additionally i want to visualize the problem and show the Region plot for
$$\frac{x-a}{x+a} \geq 0$$

